# The Font Of String Changes After Getting Record From Oracle Database

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, character-encoding

I am Retrieving data from database into a DataTable and bind a data grid. But When grid is bound there is some symbolic font that changes the last characters of strings.

[image]

Comment: is all the data stored in the database in English? are you using UTF-98

Comment: yes all data stored i english and don't knew about UTF-98 however i have tried BYTES TO STRING conversion using different Encodings. But All does not work...